# Operation on two dicts

Tags: python

I have a dict:

```
a = {<Object: object1>: [{'one': 25, 'two': 3}, {'one': 18, 'two': 2}, {'one': 10, 'two': 1}], <Object: object2>: [{'one': 25, 'two': 4}, {'one': 18, 'two': 2}], <Object: object3>: [{'one': 35, 'two': 5}, {'one': 15, 'two': 2}]}
```

Can someone explain me how to divide every item with key 'one' by item with key 'two', to do dict like this one below?

```
b = {<Object: object1>: [{8.3}, {9}, {10}], <Object: object2>: [{6.25}, {9}], <Object: object3>: [{7}, {7.5}]}
```

Comment: What do you have tried, so far?

Comment: Is it just me or does `b` not appear to be proper python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = {'o1': [{'one': 25, 'two': 3}, {'one': 18, 'two': 2}, {'one': 10, 'two': 1}],
     'o2': [{'one': 25, 'two': 4}, {'one': 18, 'two': 2}],
     'o3': [{'one': 35, 'two': 5}, {'one': 15, 'two': 2}]}

b = dict(((k, [1.0*x['one']/x['two'] for x in v]) for k, v in a.items()))
```